# Square POS App doesn't load when using Intent in Javascript

Tags: javascript, android, square-connect

I have an Andriod app that uses a WebView to load a WebApp. In the WebApp, I want to be able to click a credit button and launch the Square POS Android app. Do the swipe then use a call back to the Web App to pass the data to the WebAPI.

Here is the code I'm using.

```
        let squareAppUrl = `intent:#Intent;action=com.squareup.pos.action.CHARGE;package=com.squareup;S.browser_fallback_url=${window.location.origin}/;S.com.squareup.pos.WEB_CALLBACK_URI=${callbackUrl};S.com.squareup.pos.CLIENT_ID=${model.application_id};S.com.squareup.pos.API_VERSION=v2.0;i.com.squareup.pos.TOTAL_AMOUNT=${model.amount};S.com.squareup.pos.CURRENCY_CODE=${currency};S.com.squareup.pos.TENDER_TYPES=com.squareup.pos.TENDER_CARD,com.squareup.pos.TENDER_CARD_ON_FILE;end`;

        window.location = squareAppUrl;
        this.interval = setInterval(await this.attemptToProcessAndroidPayment.bind(this, completeCallback), this.intervalTimer);
```

edit:

I tried adding it as just a button and get this error

> net:ERR_UNKOWN_URL_SCHEME

Comment: does it work with a basic link?

Comment: @tristansokol According to Square's API docs, this is the way you're supposed to do it. I don't know of another way.

Comment: The documentation say to use a link element with the intent in an href. I'm not sure if Android will let you open an intent via JavaScript redirect, so I was asking about if you had tried using an anchor tag instead.

Comment: @tistansokol I can try that. According to the previous dev that worked on the project, they said they had it working at one point. I guess a later update to the Square app/api broke it.

Comment: Sorry, I didn't see that you had edited this. Is it possible your url you are passing for either fallback or redirect isn't actually a url. `${window.location}` seems like it could be printing an object.